# How can I iterate through array in javascript and display its content in a specific form?

Tags: jquery, pdfmake

I'm playing around with a http://pdfmake.org/#/ library that generates pdf files on demand. I can set up there directly everything that has to be printed, and since I can choose the appropriate layout, I've decided to go with a table.

So the code for the table is as follows:

```
table: {
    widths: ['*', '*', '*',200,'*', '*'], //setting up the dimension of each column
    body: [
    [ 'No1.', 'No2', 'No3', 'No4', 'No5', 'No6'], //header of each column
    [ 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef'], //first row
    [ 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef'] //second row, etc.
        ]
    }
```

I have a table filled before with a data fetched by ajax:

```
client_data = JSON.parse(response);
```

and when I do `alert(client_data)` I see `[Object object],[Object object],[Object object], etc.`. Each object contains the necessary data, so I could do e.g.:

```
var no1 = client_data.no1[0]
```

etc.
And now I want to build a loop inside the `body: [    ]` that will substitute the existing dummy rows:

```
 [ 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef'], //first row
 [ 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef'] //second row, etc.
```

with data from `client_data`. I don't know how to iterate from it and fetch the appropriate data, could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have built a simple snippet with a loop for fill the table. Paste it directly at [pdfmake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) in order to see it in action.

Regards!

```
var client_data, dataTable, i, item, len, rows;
client_data = [
  {
    prop01: 'row01.prop01',
    prop02: 'row01.prop02',
    prop03: 'row01.prop03',
    prop04: 'row01.prop04',
    prop05: 'row01.prop05',
    prop06: 'row01.prop06'
  }, {
    prop01: 'row02.prop01',
    prop02: 'row02.prop02',
    prop03: 'row02.prop03',
    prop04: 'row02.prop04',
    prop05: 'row02.prop05',
    prop06: 'row02.prop06'
  }, {
    prop01: 'row03.prop01',
    prop02: 'row03.prop02',
    prop03: 'row03.prop03',
    prop04: 'row03.prop04',
    prop05: 'row03.prop05',
    prop06: 'row03.prop06'
  }
];

dataTable = {
  style: 'table',
  table: {
    widths: ['30%', '10%', '15%', '15%', '15%', '15%'],
    headerRows: 1,
    body: [
      [
        {
          text: 'No1',
          style: 'tableHeader'
        }, {
          text: 'No2',
          style: 'tableHeader'
        }, {
          text: 'No3',
          style: 'tableHeader'
        }, {
          text: 'No4',
          style: 'tableHeader'
        }, {
          text: 'No5',
          style: 'tableHeader'
        }, {
          text: 'No6',
          style: 'tableHeader'
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  layout: {
    hLineWidth: function(i, node) {
      if (i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length) {
        return 0;
      } else if (i === node.table.headerRows) {
        return 2;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    },
    vLineWidth: function(i) {
      return 0;
    },
    hLineColor: function(i) {
      if (i === 1) {
        return '#2361AE';
      } else {
        return '#84a9d6';
      }
    },
    paddingLeft: function(i) {
      if (i === 0) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return 8;
      }
    },
    paddingRight: function(i, node) {
      if (i === node.table.widths.length - 1) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return 8;
      }
    }
  }
};

rows = dataTable.table.body;

i = 0;

len = client_data.length;

while (i < len) {
  item = client_data[i];
  rows.push([
    item.prop01, {
      text: item.prop02,
      alignment: 'right'
    }, {
      text: item.prop03,
      alignment: 'right'
    }, {
      text: item.prop04,
      alignment: 'right'
    }, {
      text: item.prop05,
      alignment: 'right'
    }, {
      text: item.prop06,
      alignment: 'center'
    }
  ]);
  i++;
}
var dd = {
    content: [],
    styles: {
        table: {
            margin: [0, 5, 0, 15]
        },
        tableHeader: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 10,
            color: '#2361AE'
        }
    },
    defaultStyle: {
        // alignment: 'justify'
    }

}

dd.content.push(dataTable)
```